# module.exportDefault is not a function

Tags: reactjs, meteor, babeljs

I'm not sure if this is a Meteor problem, but I can't find anything like it out there.

Version: Meteor2.0-beta.4, but also Meteor 1.11, 1.12

With a fresh checkout and meteor npm install, I run up the app, the server is running, and I get a javascript error in the Chrome console:

`Uncaught TypeError: module.exportDefault is not a function`

Looking at the source code, I can see it's a systematic problem, ie it is there on many modules. It's almost as if babel is compiling it wrong

```
MemoryRouter.propTypes = {
  initialEntries: PropTypes.array,
  initialIndex: PropTypes.number,
  getUserConfirmation: PropTypes.func,
  keyLength: PropTypes.number,
  children: PropTypes.node
};
module.exportDefault(MemoryRouter);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

},"Router.js":function module(require,exports,module){

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                                                                     //
// node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js                                                                              //
//                                                                                                                     //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Here is my `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-1"],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-root-import",
          {
            "paths": [{ "rootPathPrefix": "/" }]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-root-import",
      {
        "paths": [{ "rootPathPrefix": "/" }]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and dependencies from `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.27.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.27.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^20.2.0",
    "ajv": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.570.0",
    "aws-sns-sms": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "change-case": "^3.1.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "cors": "2.7.1",
    "cron": "^1.7.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "d3": "^6.2.0",
    "dagre-d3": "^0.6.4",
    "date-and-time": "^0.6.2",
    "date-utils": "^1.2.21",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.0",
    "get-canvas-context": "^1.0.2",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "inspector": "^0.5.0",
    "jsonfile": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mandrill-api": "^1.0.45",
    "markdown-it": "^8.4.2",
    "markdown-it-mermaid": "^0.2.5",
    "markdown-it-plantuml": "^1.4.1",
    "markdown-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^1.0.1",
    "meteor-redux-middlewares": "^3.0.6",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.27",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "moment-business-days": "^1.1.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "namecase": "^1.1.2",
    "nan": "^2.14.1",
    "node-gyp": "^6.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.62",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "pinjs": "^1.0.3",
    "prismjs": "^1.21.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
    "randomcolor": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^11.0.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.0.3-alpha5",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.1",
    "react-codejar": "^1.0.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^6.1.0",
    "react-data-grid-addons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.0.6",
    "react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.0.2",
    "react-markdown-it": "^1.0.2",
    "react-pivottable": "^0.10.0",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.4.4",
    "react-radio-group": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-redux-meteor": "^4.5.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-s-alert": "^1.4.1",
    "react-simple-tree-menu": "^1.0.6",
    "react-sortable-tree": "^2.8.0",
    "react-sortable-tree-theme-full-node-drag": "^1.1.0",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-split": "^2.0.4",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.87",
    "react-table": "^6.9.2",
    "react-tabulator": "^0.13.2",
    "react-tag-autocomplete": "^6.1.0",
    "react-tag-cloud": "^1.3.2",
    "react-time-line": "^0.3.0",
    "react-trello": "^2.2.8",
    "react-ui-tree": "^4.0.0",
    "react-vega": "^7.4.0",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.0.2",
    "react-x-editable": "0.0.10-beta",
    "reactabular-table": "^8.12.0",
    "recursive-readdir": "^2.2.2",
    "recursive-readdir-sync": "^1.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.73.1",
    "semantic-ui-react-numberinput": "^1.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.2.3",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.6",
    "stack-trace": "0.0.10",
    "stackedit-js": "^1.0.7",
    "svg-text-size": "0.0.1",
    "svg-text-wrap": "0.0.1",
    "svg-to-image": "^1.1.3",
    "tabulator-tables": "^4.7.2",
    "tracker-component": "^1.3.21",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "underscore.deepclone": "^0.1.3",
    "uniforms": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "uniforms-bootstrap4": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "uniforms-bridge-json-schema": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "uniforms-bridge-simple-schema-2": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "uninstall": "0.0.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "vega": "^5.13.0",
    "vega-lite": "^4.17.0",
    "vertical-timeline-component-for-react": "^1.0.6",
    "winston": "=3.1.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.7.2",
    "winston-loggly-bulk": "git+https://github.com/loggly/winston-loggly-bulk.git#3.x",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.7.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-options": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.0.26",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.8.0",
    "child-process": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "cypress": "^4.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.2.0",
    "jest-meteor-stubs": "^1.5.1",
    "mocha": "^7.1.2",
    "newman": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.11.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.2",
    "sinon": "^6.0.0",
    "storybook-react-router": "^1.0.8"
  }
```

`.meteor/packages` file:

```
meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.1.0       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.10.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.7.0-beta200.4   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.6.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.15.0-beta200.4              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.5.0            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command
fixtures
dynamic-import@0.6.0-beta200.4
accounts-password@1.6.2
accounts-ui@1.3.1
aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.0
mdg:validated-method
react-meteor-data
accounts-base@1.7.0
grove:call-async
practicalmeteor:chai
practicalmeteor:mocha
meteortesting:mocha
dburles:factory
mikkelking:cleaner
meteorhacks:aggregate
ostrio:files
dburles:mongo-collection-instances
underscore@1.0.10
#force-ssl@1.1.0
accounts-github@1.4.3
meteoreact:accounts-semantic
meteoreact:accounts
jquery
akryum:mysql
alanning:roles@2.1.0
static-html
fourseven:scss
hot-module-replacement@0.2.0-beta200.4
mikkelking:slingshot
mikkelking:method-hooks
```

I have tried updating the babel libraries, but with no wins :(

Any ideas would be appreciated

### UPDATE @1/12/20

`meteor add modules` didn't work (shame, it would have been nice)

I have worked out that it's related to one or more npm modules. If I preserve a working package-lock.json, it works ok, but if I remove it and do a `meteor npm install`, then I get this error. I am seeing some huge memory usage and bad performance with it (even with Meteor 1.11.1), which is probably related. npm updates too many packages to be able to track down the culprit easily.

Comment: Can you add the `.meteor/packages` list please? I'd like to reproduce this in a fresh 1.11 project and see where this comes from.

Comment: When I create a fresh project, add all your dependencies in package.json, run `meteor npm install`, and then start the app I actually get a seg fault. I want to say that one/some of your dependencies break things but I can't say for sure or which one.

Comment: BTW, why do you need a babel rc file?

Comment: I'm able to get past the segfault by removing node-gyp from the dependencies. I do not get the error you are seeing then either, but I also haven't added the babelrc file yet.

Comment: I added the `.meteor/packages` file. Good idea to put them into a blank project. Thanks for lending a hand guys! I have a `.babelrc` file because I'm using jest

Comment: FYI meteor does not have a proper bundling system like webpack or parcel. If you run into a loading problem because your bundles are too large, then they propose ECMA non-standard feature to nest your import statements (by standard they are only allowed on top level of your module).  I'd recommend avoiding meteor if you can.

Comment: @Jackson that doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @Jackson It doesn't help at all too, and I think meteor already has a proper bundling system to deploy, of course.

Comment: @Chandan I was very hopeful, and added modules, but the problem remains. See update in question

Comment: @kakadais they are working on tree-shaking which will be released in 2.0, until then it does not have proper bundling see [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/labels/Project%3ATree%20shaking).

Answer (score 0):

I personally never used Meteor but from the looks of it, Meteor would need to define exportDefault. Having a look at this [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8755) it seems that `meteor install modules` needs to happen to support exportDefault.

Comment: That looks interesting, and possibly a solution

Comment: Looking forward to knowing if it did help.

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid, it did sound like it was going to work. Currently creating a new project, and moving code into it

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear. Make sure you test it with each new package introduce. Since the above didn't work, my guess is a namespace collision might be happening and erasing Meteor's exportDefault.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking along the same lines. Perhaps `module` is being replaced, which would explain it. Actually we found a rogue import in the code: `import { None } from 'vega'` - removing that seems to fix it, although there are other performance issues I am concerned about - not counting my chickens yet